# How do I recreate the custom column filter values (checkboxes)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a help where I need to recreate the options for column filter values when the data on left hand side filter changes?

I have a drop down list country on left hand side and when ever user select the country the column(region), filter (custom filter, based on column on the grid) all the checkboxes for the custom filter should reflect the region as per the country selected.

** I need to find the way to update the datasource on the field after this is initailized**

Comment: There's lots of way to manipulate the DataSource after its initialized. Refer to [this doc](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods). But you didnt gave us an example, a print, nothing. We don't have a crystal ball.